# How to dispose of Javascript objects using the Dispose method?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

There are some heavy JS objects I would like to clean up using the dispose method.
I use `IJSObjectReference` to call JS code.

The code:

```
public partial class BlazorComponent : IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private IJSObjectReference? _jsModule;

    // ...

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsync(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeAsync(true); // Won't be awaited
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private async ValueTask DisposeAsync(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        if (_jsModule is not null)
            await _jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("deleteHeavyObject");

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_jsModule is not null)
                await _jsModule.DisposeAsync();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    ~BlazorComponent()
    {
        DisposeAsync(false); // Won't be awaited
    }
}
```

The `IJSObjectReference` only implements `IAsyncDisposable` and you can only call JS methods via async methods.

What is the best practice to deal with this situation?

I could do `DisposeAsync(...).AsTask().Wait()` or I could just not implement `IDispose` and the deconstructor because it looks like in Blazor [Dispose/DisposeAsync gets called regardless of the `GC`](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/)?

Comment: Why are you implementing a finalizer and `IDisposable` at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I need to dispose the JS object and I followed the best practices for the dispose pattern. I don't know if it's needed tho, as I mentioned in the post. I couldn't find any resources on how the GC in Balzor WASM works (or if there even is one). The most helpful resource I could find is this [Component life](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/) where it looks like a finalizer isn't needed because Blazor calls  the `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` implementation regardless of any GC.

Comment: The [first rule of finalizers is "don't implement it unless you need to"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/first-rule-of-implementing-idisposable.html) (link is to my blog). In this case, since your type contains a component that only implements `IAsyncDisposable`, then your type should only implement `IAsyncDisposable`. Then you don't have any problems.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74928714/9971404) for related issue and solutions.