# JSDisconnectedException Thrown on Page Refresh at DisposeAsync() in Blazor Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor

To load an isolated JavaScript module in Blazor Server, I have an `IJSObjectReference`, `module`, that is initialized in `OnAfterRenderAsync` as follows:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Shared/Component.razor.js");
        }
 }
```

The module is successfully imported. 
However, when I attempt to dispose of the object reference in the razor component's `IASyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` method, I receive an error in Blazor Server whenever a disposal attempt is made (such as on page refresh, for example):

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSDisconnectedException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the circuit has disconnected and is being disposed.
```

The `DisposeAsync` implementation is shown below:

```
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
        if (module is not null)   // Dispose of resources if created
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();   // Error occurs at this line
        }
}
```

Removing the `module.DisposeAsync()` line prevents the error from occurring, but this would surely lead to a memory leak. I am uncertain of the source of the interop error since I am unaware of any JavaScript being invoked during the disposal process. 
How can I properly dispose of the `IJSObjectReference`?

Comment: See the following questions and answers:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928714/blazor-component-removed-from-dom-before-disposal-causes-js-interop-to-fail   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726700/how-to-dispose-of-javascript-objects-using-the-dispose-method.   My answer to the first question explains why you see the error and there are some suggestions for solutions in the various answers.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks for these, I had seen them but assumed they did not apply to me as I did not explicitly make use of `InvokeAsync` in my `DisposeAsync` implementation. However I now realize that invoking `DisposeAsync` on a `JSObjectReference` implicitly does this, so I have used try-catch on the `JSDisconnectedException` to solve the issue as per [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38822)

Comment: Wrapping it in a `try...catch` doesn't fix the problem, it just restricts it's scope to the method.  Every attempt to dispose will trigger the catch.  It's the same result as not calling `DisposeAsync` at all.  You should run some testing and memory monitoring on a running application to see if it's actually a problem.  If it is, you'll need to implement one of the suggested solutions.

Comment: `module.DisposeAsync` executed successfully when switching pages, and is vetoed when reloading the tab which avoids the error

Comment: Without a proper context I was just advising.  You have it covered so np. ;-)

Comment: Yes apologies for being a little light on the context, thanks for the help!